# Handling file upload aborting by xmlhttprequest on nodejs backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, xmlhttprequest, koa

I've implemented sending files from React frontend to nodeJS (koa v1) backend by XMLHttpRequest specially to get ability to track file upload progress. As an addition I decided to add upload cancel by standard `xhr.abort()` function. It's ok, works very well on client side but every time I get `Parse Error` thrown by backend:

```
Error: Parse Error
 at Error (native)
 at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_server.js:422:22)
 at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
 at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
 at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:973:12)
 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Below is code of controller which handles file stream and saves them to local machine. Before it `formData` is  parsed by `co-busboy`

```
module.exports.saveFiles = function* (files) {
  const savedFiles = [];
  let file = yield files;

  while (file) {
    const fileName = file.filename;
    const fileExt = path.extname(fileName);
    const newFileName = `${generator.generate()}${fileExt}`;
    const filePath = path.join(config.uploadFolder, newFileName);

    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    file.pipe(stream);

    savedFiles.push({
      fileId: newFileName,
      fileName,
      mimeType: file.mimeType,
    });

    file = yield files;
  }

  return savedFiles;
};
```

As you can see I have used readable stream from file and writable stream to save it , and here is a problem because I can't handle `Parse Error` here, I've tried to use `error` and `end` events on both of these streams but they just didn't emit, the same situation with wrapping by `try catch`. The only way to catch this error is top level `app.on('error', cb)` middleware, but it's far away from my controller.

So is there any way to catch error inside my controller and send correct response to client?